# Implementing skip connections in Autoencoder using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm building a variational autoencoder. When trying to implement skip connections, I get the error:

```
shape=(None, 136, 168, 1), dtype=float32) at layer "encoder_conv_layer_1". 
The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

I've done a bit of digging and came to realise that the error is indeed with the skip connections. However, I had no luck in finding a solution in any of the threads I consulted.

The relevant parts of the code are as follows:

```
import os
import pickle
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, ReLU, BatchNormalization, \
    Flatten, Dense, Reshape, Conv2DTranspose, Activation, Dropout, Concatenate, Lambda
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.losses import MeanSquaredError
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import nibabel as nib
import sys
from tensorflow.keras.initializers import he_normal

class VAE:

    def __init__(self,
                 input_shape,
                 conv_filters,
                 conv_kernels,
                 conv_strides,
                 latent_space_dim):
        self.input_shape = input_shape 
        self.conv_filters = conv_filters 
        self.conv_kernels = conv_kernels 
        self.conv_strides = conv_strides 
        self.latent_space_dim = latent_space_dim 
        self.reconstruction_loss_weight = 0.1

        self.encoder = None
        self.decoder = None
        self.model = None

        self._num_conv_layers = len(conv_filters)
        self._shape_before_bottleneck = None
        self._model_input = None 
        self.encoder_outputs = []

        self._build()
        
        
    def _build(self):

        self.encoder_outputs = []
        self._build_encoder()
        self._build_decoder()
        self._build_autoencoder()


    def summary(self):

        self.encoder.summary()
        self.decoder.summary()
        self.model.summary()

    def _build_autoencoder(self):

        model_input = self._model_input
        model_output = self.decoder(self.encoder(model_input))
        self.model = Model(model_input, model_output, name = "autoencoder")   


    def _build_decoder(self):

        decoder_input = self._add_decoder_input()
        dense_layer = self._add_dense_layer(decoder_input)
        reshape_layer = self._add_reshape_layer(dense_layer)
        conv_transpose_layers = self._add_conv_transpose_layers(reshape_layer)
        decoder_output = self._add_decoder_output(conv_transpose_layers)
        self.decoder = Model(decoder_input, decoder_output, name = "decoder")


    def _add_decoder_input(self):

        return Input(shape = self.latent_space_dim, name = "decoder_input")


    def _add_dense_layer(self, decoder_input):

        num_neurons = np.prod(self._shape_before_bottleneck) 
        dense_layer = Dense(num_neurons, name = "decoder_dense")(decoder_input)
        return dense_layer
    

    def _add_reshape_layer(self, dense_layer):
        
        reshape_layer = Reshape(self._shape_before_bottleneck)(dense_layer)
        return reshape_layer
    


    def _add_conv_transpose_layers(self, x):
        
        for layer_index in reversed(range(1, self._num_conv_layers)):
            x = Concatenate()([x, self.encoder_outputs[layer_index]])  # Skip connection
            x = self._add_conv_transpose_layer(layer_index, x)

        return x

    def _add_conv_transpose_layer(self, layer_index, x):
    
        layer_num = self._num_conv_layers - layer_index 
        conv_transpose_layer = Conv2DTranspose(
            filters = self.conv_filters[layer_index],
            kernel_size = self.conv_kernels[layer_index],
            strides = self.conv_strides[layer_index],
            padding = "same",
            kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.he_normal(),  # He.Normal initializer
            name = f"decoder_conv_transpose_layer_{layer_num}"
        )
        x = conv_transpose_layer(x)
        x = ReLU(name = f"decoder_ReLU_{layer_num}")(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(name = f"decoder_BN_{layer_num}")(x)
        x = Dropout(0.5, name = f"decoder_dropout_{layer_num}")(x)  # 50% dropout; adjust as needed

        return x


    def _add_decoder_output(self, x):

        conv_transpose_layer = Conv2DTranspose(
            filters = 1,
            kernel_size = self.conv_kernels[0],
            strides = self.conv_strides[0],
            padding = "same",
            kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.he_normal(),  # He.Normal initializer
            name = f"decoder_conv_transpose_layer_{self._num_conv_layers}"
        )
        x = conv_transpose_layer(x)
        output_layer = Activation("sigmoid", name = "Sigmoid_layer")(x)

        return output_layer


    def _build_encoder(self):

        encoder_input = Input(shape=self.input_shape, name="encoder_input")
        conv_layers = self._add_conv_layers(encoder_input)
        bottleneck = self._add_bottleneck(conv_layers)
        self._model_input = encoder_input
        self.encoder = Model(encoder_input, bottleneck, name="encoder")


    def _add_encoder_input(self):

        return Input(shape=self.input_shape, name="encoder_input")


    def _add_conv_layers(self, encoder_input):
        """Create all convolutional blocks in encoder."""
        x = encoder_input
        for layer_index in range(self._num_conv_layers):
            x = self._add_conv_layer(layer_index, x)
            self.encoder_outputs.append(x)
        
        return x


    def _add_conv_layer(self, layer_index, x):

        layer_number = layer_index + 1
        conv_layer = Conv2D(
            filters = self.conv_filters[layer_index],
            kernel_size = self.conv_kernels[layer_index],
            strides = self.conv_strides[layer_index],
            padding = "same",
            kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.he_normal(),  # He.Normal initializer
            name = f"encoder_conv_layer_{layer_number}"
        )
        x = conv_layer(x)
        x = ReLU(name = f"encoder_relu_{layer_number}")(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(name = f"encoder_bn_{layer_number}")(x)
        x = Dropout(0.5, name = f"encoder_dropout_{layer_number}")(x)

        return x

    def _add_bottleneck(self, x):

        self._shape_before_bottleneck = K.int_shape(x)[1:]
        x = Flatten()(x)
        self.mu = Dense(self.latent_space_dim, 
                        kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.he_normal(),  # He.Normal initializer
                        name = "mu")(x)
        self.log_variance = Dense(self.latent_space_dim,
                                   kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.he_normal(),  # He.Normal initializer
                                   name = "log_variance")(x)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

I've tried workarounds and see if the indexes of the layers being passed were the problem, but nothing seemed to work. The tensor dimensions seem to be correct.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).